# Is there a way to configure the Kafka client timeout settings in Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

When starting a Spring Cloud Data Flow stream, quite often the apps fail to deploy on my machine because of various Kafka related errors. For instance:
`org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Cannot initialize binder
    [...]
    Caused by: kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(xxx)] from broker [List()] failed`

But I've also seen this:
`kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0`

In both situations, the Kafka process is running (as well as ZooKeeper), so I assume there is some sort of timeout threshold passed.

Neither the [generic](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_options) nor the [Kafka-specific](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_specific_settings) configuration seems to offer any timeout options.

Is there any way I can influence the amount of time after which the Kafka client gives up and assumes the broker is gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you fetch the topics info using kafka tool commands such as `./bin/kafka-topics.sh`? It appears like a Kafka configuration issue than a possible timeout.

If you want to set any of the generic properties (like connect.timeout.ms etc.,) in kafka producer/consumer, you can do it via `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.<producer/consumer>.configuration.<propertyName>=<propertyValue>`

Answer (score 0):

it seems the kafka broker did not run correctly, can u try using
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper <your zookeeper host>:2181` to see whether ur topic is in sync or not.